# Using UiApp.createApplication() twice in Googlesites

Tags: google-apps-script

I have wrote a script that was run from a spreadsheet.

I had

- One main UI
- One warning UiApp, that will be showed when details entered by the user matched a certain criteria.

I used two functions that used two different,

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
 /*....
   ....
   .... */
doc.show(app);
```

However, when i used Googlesite's script editor, i could create only one UIapp, using doget(e).

Whenever i use,

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
```

in another function, it doesnt work out well, Is it possible to have more than one UiApps or should i use only one UI for my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call createApplication() twice. It will result in an error. Consider using the DialogBox widget for showing a message on top of an existing UI.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_dialogbox